# Refresh page with new parameters using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a dropdown which supposed to order my view . I managed doing it with this code :

```
function DropdownChange(sortOrder) {
  var dropdown = $('#sortBy');
  dropdown.value = sortOrder;
  var checkBox = $('#descending').is(":checked");
  var tmp = "?sortOrder=" + sortOrder;

  if ('@ViewBag.CurrentFilter' != "")
    tmp = tmp + "&currentFilter=" + '@ViewBag.CurrentFilter';

  if (checkBox == true)
    tmp = tmp + "&descending=" + checkBox;

  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetAllMovies", "Movie")' + tmp;
}
```

But the request to the server isn't being done by Ajax (which I was requested to do) . I tried replacing `window.location.href` with this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Movie/GetAllMovies/',
  type:'GET',
  data: tmp,
  success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    document.location.reload(); 
  }
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The page is indeed refreshed , but without the new parameters I've sent on the `data` .

What I want to call the controller method with the new parameters, and rerender the view with the new data .

**EDIT**: As @ RoryMcCrossan suggested in the comments, I tried this :

```
  success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    $(".someContainer").html(data)
  }
```

The page is rerendered , but the data displayed doesn't change, although it should change..

Comment: If you're using AJAX then you need to remove the `document.location.reload()` call and then you'll have to manually update the page with the response you get from the AJAX call in the `data` argument

Comment: I tried that, perhaps I didn't do it right but it didn't work either. I tried selecting from the layout the container and putting the data there.. like this : `$(".someContainer").html = data;` but nothing happens .. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Assuming `data` is a HTML string, then that needs to be `$(".someContainer").html(data)`. See the docs: https://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: Calling the page reload in success defeats the purpose of using Ajax. Use the data returned in `data` to update your elements using jQuery. You don't have to refresh the whole page.

Comment: Thanks. The page is refreshed now, but again without any parameters @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @lurker see my edit..

Comment: Try `console.log(tmp)` before making the AJAX request to see what values you send

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it looks correct.. if I manually enter it to the url it works.

Comment: Check the request in dev tools to make sure the data is actually being sent in the request

Comment: Just to be clear, the URL of the page will not change if that it what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Ajax requests should return something meaningful, check that the response actually returns anything? Then utilise [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to manage URL changes...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the help, still learning Ajax concepts.. checking the request with devtools helped:) There was a problem with the parameters I've passed through data(an unnecessary ? in the beggining) it works now.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)